# Role of tty in Linux kernel

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, operating-system, tty

I was going through the source code of Linux version 0.0.1. In the kernel source directory saw a file tty_io.c. What is the role of this file/tty in Linux kernel?

Comment: See http://www.linusakesson.net/programming/tty/ ; BTW kernel 0.0.1 has only historical interest.

Comment: Can i say tty is a piece of code that is responsible for the input and output services to terminal? And which will run continuously and go to sleep when the services from tty is no needed?

Comment: That's close. A `tty` is the representation of the terminal, and what you're looking at is a `tty` device driver.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Unix systems, a `tty` (which is short for "teletypewriter") is the standard representation of a [terminal device](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_terminal), with at least input and output capabilities and usually much more. These were originally connected to serial ports, but most today are *virtual terminals*, connected to either a text-mode console (DOS-like) or a graphical terminal program (like `xterm` or `gnome-terminal`).

Answer (score 0):

This file is to support `tty` on user level interface or console.This also implements echoing.

`tty`: Print file name of terminal on standard input.For more info give `info tty` command on shell.